# Calculate commerce product sales price based on order quantity

Tags: commerce

The commerce price table module is meant for calculating the sales price on commerce products based on order quantities. But out of the box the contrib module commerce_price_table prices do not get calculated to sales prices. In my case I have a tax rate per product that is nicely applied to the standard commerce product price but not to the commerce_price_table prices.

Is there another way to calculate the product sales price based on order quantity? Might this be fully configurable with Rules?

For a related topic see [www.drupal.org/node/1886080](https://www.drupal.org/node/1886080)
There is also an alternative module [www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pricelist](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pricelist) but this one is still in alpha.